# Matplotlib saving image of figure to the size of elements in the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to take the dimensions of a cube and convert it into a net that can then be printed off, the only issue in completing this is that when I save the net as a png I can't get the size of the edges correct.

As shown in the code below, I have looked into sizing the entire figure proportionally to the size of the shapes, setting dpi, equal aspect ratios, limiting the graph to make it fit and also just plain not sizing it at all. I feel like there must be a simple solution to this but I just can't get my head around all the options and if I should only use one or if more together would be better.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def data(l, h, w):
    locations = [(w, 0), (w,w), (w, w + h), (w, w + h + w), (l + w, w), (0, w)]
    sizes = [[l,w], [l,h], [l,w], [l,h],[w,h],[w,h]]
    return locations, sizes
        
def automate(l,h, w, circleR):
    locs, siz = data(l, h, w)
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(12,12)
    #ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 200), ylim=(0, 200))
    for x in range (6):
        plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle(locs[x],siz[x][0], siz[x][1], ec='black',fc='None'))
    plt.axis('scaled')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig('Map.png')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    automate(7,4,1) #My test case was 7 inches by 4 inches by 1 inch
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to take into account:

- the axes decorations (labels, ticks, ticklabels, etc.) take some space in the figure, and you may have to take those into account. Best to create an `Axes` that occupies the full space of the figure using `ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`
- don't use `tight_layout()` because it will change the dimensions of your axes (and possibly the figure) which makes the result unpredictable.
- you can plot directly in `inches` using a transformation [`fig.dpi_scale_trans`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)

```py
def automate(l,h, w, figsize=(12,12), dpi=100, origin=(0,0)):
    locs, siz = data(l, h, w)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize,dpi=dpi)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.axis('off')
    for l,s in zip(locs,siz):
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(np.array(origin)+np.array(l),s[0], s[1], ec='black',fc='None', transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans))
    fig.savefig('test.png')


automate(7,4,1, origin=(1,1)) #My test case was 7 inches by 4 inches by 1 inch
```

[image]